# Run Adobe CC Programs in WINE?

Tags: wine

Is it possible to install the Creative Cloud on WINE? I tried to run it using default settings and it crashes instantly. Was hoping someone got this working. Right now I dual boot Win and Ubuntu, and my whole workflow is so much faster, except when I have to do Video Editing and I need both After Effects and Premier Pro. Both of which are on my Windows boot. 
I Tried using Open shot, and its too buggy, not enough features, and crashes my desktop when trying to do anything with it.

Comment: While I don't have Adobe CC, it would probably be helpful to those that may be able to answer your question if you provided the Wine version. Also, have you checked the wine [AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org)?

Comment: My version, I believe, is wine1.6 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4. and yes I looked through the database, but it seems most people just use older versions

Comment: My only advice until somebody that's a little more experience with getting Adobe software work in wine: Try this 1.7 development version: `sudo apt-add-ppa ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install wine1.7`. If you want to revert, no need to delete the PPA, just `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`